# Count error with annotate() & values() while filtering categories, repetition

Tags: django

Django : Count error  with annotate() & values() while filtering categories, duplication error as I'm using below count function to filter categories but its displaying accountant separately twice.

```
    queryset = Blogpost \
        .objects \
        .values('categories__title') \
        .annotate(Count('categories__title'))
    return queryset 

> My function in template 

{% for cat in category_count %}
            <div class="item d-flex justify-content-between">
                <a href="#">{{ cat.categories__title }}</a><span>{{ cat.categories__title__count }}</span>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Share your `BlogPost` and `Category` model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=15)`

Comment: `class Blogpost(models.Model):
     post_id = models.AutoField(primary_key= True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='shop/images', default="")
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
    objects = models.Manager()
    featured = models.BooleanField()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should order by the name, so:

```
queryset = Blogpost.objects.values('categories__title').annotate(
    Count('categories__title')
).order_by('categories__title')
```

But it is actually *not* a good idea to query the `Blogpost` model. You can query from the `Category` model:

```
Category.objects.annotate(
    count=Count('blogpost')
)
```

We here thus annotate the `Category`s with the number of blogposts, then we can render this with:

```
{% for cat in category_count %}
    <div class="item d-flex justify-content-between">
        <a href="#">{{ cat.title }}</a><span>{{ cat.count }}</span>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```